How to make numpy compatibile with pandas?
I am getting constantly this error after:
import pandas as pd

ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.20.3 
your numpy version is 1.20.2. 
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.20.3 to use this pandas version

How to solve this? How to make "import pandas as pd" run properly?
BTW if I follow this automatic suggestion by installing numpy==1.20.3 it doesn't solve this compatibility issue.

os.system("pip install numpy==1.20.3") that's a bad idea. You don't really know on which python, and which python environment you install numpy here. And particularly, you don't know if you are installing numpy for the same python you are currently running in. Obviously this pip is running in one where 1.20.3 is already installed, when your python is running without 1.20.3

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Upgrade both libraries. You can do this using pip.
to upgrade numpy run:
pip install --upgrade numpy

And for pandas run:
pip install --upgrade pandas

If the issue persists, try uninstalling them by running:
pip uninstall numpy pandas

And reinstalling them with:
pip install numpy pandas


Make sure that you are using pip in the correct environment, and run pip list to verify which version of NumPy and Pandas you're using.
NumPy 1.20.3 has been required since Pandas 1.5 or thereabouts, with 1.22.4 required for the latest version of Pandas (2.2, as of right now), and 2.1 the latest version of NumPy.
Assuming everything looks correct, unless you have a particular reason for using an earlier version, I would recommend just upgrading NumPy all the way with pip install numpy --upgrade. Possibly also upgrade Pandas while you're at it since 1.20.3 hasn't been the minimum requirement since Pandas < 2.1.0
